# Django - Preselect options in MultipleChoiceField

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a class form that has the forms.MultipleChoiceField in it.

I am able to render it and show all the choices to select / highlight, but what I want is the choices that get displayed to be pre-highlighted. so it is up to the user to either deselect the options or leave them as they are when they submit the form.

Is there a way to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to set `initial` values to your field like this:

```
class YourForm(forms.Form):
    choices = (
          ('choice1':'choice1'),
          ('choice2':'choice2'),
          ('choice3':'choice3')
           )
   #for example if you want to select choice1 and choice2
   initial_values = ['choice1', 'choice2']
   field = forms.MultipleChoiceField(initial=initial_values)
```

Comment: I tried to do this after I instantiated the form. so basically I did f = YourForm() and then f.initial = {'blah' : 'bar'}. Also I tried doing f.fields['blah'].initial = ['foo']

Comment: This worked for me, but what I realise why I am not seeing them working on a web page is because my django template is not rendering the page correctly to have the selected= option in each of the choices I have set in initial. I will post another question relating to that.

Comment: picked = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=choices, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), initial=initial_values)

Answer (score 1):

Use Django ModelForm to do this. When instantiating, provide inital data to the form.

For example:

```
def your_view(request):
    form = YourModelForm(initial={'choice_field_name': list of choices})
```

Comment: I have tried this and it just does not seem to work. I have the choice filed name correct and I certainly put the value that is put in the multiplechoicefield. so for example : if the choice field is called "blah" and the values passed to the form are in a tuple of ('foo', 'bar'). So the initial I have done is this: initial={'blah': 'bar'}

Comment: Note: If you have a request in "form = " such as "request.POST or None" it is simply "form = YourModelForm(request.POST or None, initial={'choice_field_name': 'list of choices'})"